# Cannot display JSON response data in Vue template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

Following a video tutorial on vue and nodejs full-stack web development. I can't get JSON output response from node.js API to display in a vue.js template notifying users their account has been created successfully. Though the error is showing validation message from Postman but can't display it on the frontend with vue.

I have tried to async and await my vue register method before grabbing the JSON data response.

Register Component

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: null
    }
  },
   methods:{
     async register () {
       try {
         await AuthenticationService.register({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
       })
       }catch (error) {
         this.error = error.responce.data.error
       }
      }
     }
   } 
</script>
```

Here's how I'm displaying it on the vue template

```
<div class="error" v-html="error" />
```

I was getting an error "[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" from Google Chrome Console.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo in `error.responce`, it should be `error.response`

Comment: it works, you saved me some time. thanks so much

Comment: Glad i could help :)